# How to scale margin based on screen sizes with auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

Imagine I have a `UIImageView` with a certain aspect ratio constraint (this handles the height/bottom constraint), pinned to `superview`'s top, leading, trailing with 5pt in a 100pt width screen in XIB/storyboard. This way, if the screen size changes, the image view can scale accordingly.

That is 5pt+5pt (10pt) of margin spacing in a 100pt width screen, with image taking up 90pt (90% of the screen).

However I would like the margin spacing to be scaled as well.

How can I make it such that, on a bigger phone, e.g. with width 1000pt (10x previous), the margin will now correspondingly be 50pt+50pt (100pt) with the image taking up the remaining 900pt of the screen, retaining 90%? (This could be further complicated if we are making the horizontal constraints different, e..g. leading be 15pt while the trailing be 45pt.)

If we do it 'normally' without scaling the margin pt, the constraints of leading/trailing would be 5pt (for a total of 10pt in a 1000pt or even a 1000000pt width phone!). This is not what we usually want.

How can we achieve this easily with auto layout? I thought of class sizes but that does not fit what I am trying to do (to cater to all devices of any size).

Comment: There are a couple ways to do this... are you looking for a Storyboard approach or a code approach?

Comment: I am looking for both preferably but now I hope to have the storyboard/xib approach (which should be able to translate directly into code too I think?)

Answer (score 2):

ASFAIK there is no way to define leading or trailing constraints relatively to another view's width.

To achieve what you want you can set the following constraints on the `UIImageView`:

1. A constant **top** constraint
2. A **centerX** constraint to center the image horizontally
3. A constant **aspect ratio** constraint with your desired aspect ratio
4. A **width** constraint with the same width as the UIImageView's superview and a multiplier of 0.9 (90%)

When you do this, the horizontal margins of the image will always be 10% of the screen size.

[image]

**EDIT:**

When you also need a relative top margin you could put the UIImageView into another UIView (the one with the gray background) and use the following constraints:

1. A constant **bottom** constraint (zero if you don't want a bottom margin)
2. A **centerX** constraint to center the image horizontally
3. A constant **aspect ratio** constraint with your desired aspect ratio
4. A **width** constraint with the same width as the UIImageView's superview and a multiplier of 0.9 (90%)
5. A **height** constraint with the same height as the UIImageView's superview and a multiplier of 0.9 (90% or whatever value you desire)

[image]

If you want to have a top margin that is the same as the horizontal margins, you have to calculate it like this: `verticalMultiplier = horizontalMultiplier / (2 * aspectRatio)`

Comment: Thanks for this, what if I need to also scale the margin from the top, without modifying the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @CyberMew Please check my edit for a possible solution

Comment: For the imageview inside a new uiview, if we set imageview to be 90% of its superview (the new uiview), what do we set for the height for this uiview? Also, may I know why the formula above for verticalMultiplier is 2, and do we do this in code only and not storyboard? Thanks!

Comment: You don't set the height of the UIImageView. It is defined by its width and the aspect constraint. You have to divide by 2 because there are two horizontal margins and you only want 1 vertical margin (the top). You calculate that value and then put it in the multiplier input in the storyboard. Nothing is done in code in my example

Comment: I mean the height of the UIImageView's superview (the one with grey background), do we need to configure the constraints for that? Seems like 1-5 is for UIImageView but not for the gray UIView.. 
As for the formula, I understand now, it is for calculating the multiplier ratio manually and putting in the constraint multiplier, thanks!

Comment: The grey UIView already has a (same height as the UIImageView divided by 0.9 (or other multiplier) height constraint. The chain of layout definitions in this example runs like this:

ScreenWidth x 0.9 -> UIImageView.width
UIImageView.width / aspect ration -> UIImageView.height
UIImageView.height / 0.9 (or other multiplier) -> UIView.height

Everything is already set here. If you are wondering why I wrote "/ 0.9" in the last line: The UImageView's height is defined as same height as the UIView multiplied by 0.9. That also means that the UIView is the Image height divided by 0.9 (or other)

Answer (score 1):

Whether laying this out in Storyboard / IB or doing it via code, probably the easiest way is to use a horizontal stack view, with a (clear) "spacer" view on each side.

What you have to decide in advance, though, is the desired *proportion*.

That is, we say the leading space should be `5-pts` based on a total width of `100-pts` ... or `25-pts` based on `150-pts` ... etc.

So our stack view will have 3 arranged subviews:

- "LeftSpacer"
- imageView (with, let's say, a `640:360` ratio)
- "RightSpacer"

Constrain the Width of the LeftSpacer to the width of the stack view, with a multiplier of `(left space)/100`.

Constrain the Width of the RightSpacer to the width of the stack view, with a multiplier of `(right space)/100`.

Here are two examples.

The Top stack view has both left and right spacers set to `5/100`. The Bottom stack view has `Left: 5/100` and `Right: 45/100`. In both stack views, the image view is set to `640:360` aspect ratio (because that's the image I had handy).

This is how it looks with stack view `Width: 100`:

[image]

Top example - both spacer views are 5-pts, image view is 90-pts

Bottom example - left spacer: 5-pts, right: 45-pts, image view: 50-pts

and stack view `Width: 200`:

[image]

Top example - both spacer views are 10-pts, image view is 180-pts

Bottom example - left spacer: 10-pts, right: 90-pts, image view: 100-pts

and stack view `Width: 300`:

[image]

Top example - both spacer views are 15-pts, image view is 270-pts

Bottom example - left spacer: 15-pts, right: 135-pts, image view: 150-pts

This is the Document Outline:

[image]

and the Storyboard source if you want to inspect it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="19529" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="19519"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--SomeVC-->
        <scene sceneID="YpP-O8-TWi">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="P90-ov-dhs" customClass="SomeVC" customModule="TabBased" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Afn-4E-CtW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EZB-9U-TcY">
                                <rect key="frame" x="10" y="20" width="300" height="264.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wTh-HR-1cy">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="300" height="152"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WVJ-wZ-t9Z" userLabel="LeftSpacerView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="15" height="152"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                            </view>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="bkg640x360" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="39U-sA-bbn">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="15" y="0.0" width="270" height="152"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="39U-sA-bbn" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="640:360" id="soT-yc-UP0"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Tww-ar-yol" userLabel="RightSpacerView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="285" y="0.0" width="15" height="152"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Tww-ar-yol" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="wTh-HR-1cy" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="5/100" id="DLh-N4-vfJ"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="WVJ-wZ-t9Z" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="wTh-HR-1cy" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="5/100" id="qYi-Rk-ZOI"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TsK-Kw-YRa">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="180" width="300" height="84.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iw4-he-3pJ" userLabel="LeftSpacerView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="15" height="84.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                            </view>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="bkg640x360" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="P4f-Bc-9F2">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="15" y="0.0" width="150" height="84.5"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="P4f-Bc-9F2" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="640:360" id="ZqY-ss-ToB"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Fs5-7r-dME" userLabel="RightSpacerView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="165" y="0.0" width="135" height="84.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="iw4-he-3pJ" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="TsK-Kw-YRa" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="5/100" id="D5C-Yo-YOh"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Fs5-7r-dME" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="TsK-Kw-YRa" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="45/100" id="ajJ-GY-bZW"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="300" id="Hel-XG-PhB"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Ur7-hW-kek"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="EZB-9U-TcY" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Afn-4E-CtW" secondAttribute="centerX" id="5lZ-RK-pgy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="EZB-9U-TcY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Ur7-hW-kek" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="bg6-Jx-gi9"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="ZhN-1l-tl9"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Rgh-e1-NRf" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-118.125" y="1365"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="bkg640x360" width="640" height="360"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Obviously, that would be straightforward to replicate in code.

If, for some reason, you don't want to use stack views, you could do essentially the same thing with leading/trailing and proportional width constraints on two "side spacer views" or, to make it just a little more light-weight, use `ConstraintLayoutGuide` instead of a clear view.

---

**Edit** - for a little more clarification...

First, I should have specified that by **ConstraintLayoutGuide** I was referring to `UILayoutGuide` - whoops :(

The task you've outlined:

> If my view is 100-pts wide, I want the subview to have 5-pts "padding" on the left and right. But, as the view gets wider the padding should expand proportionally. So, if the view is 200-pts wide, the padding should be 10-pts on each side.

Could also be described as:

> I want **5%** "padding" on each side.

Auto-layout does not have a way to set the Leading anchor to a percentage of the superview's width.

So, traditionally, we used clear-background "spacer" views:

[image]

With iOS 9, Apple introduced `UILayoutGuide` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide)):

> **Overview**
>
> Use layout guides to replace the placeholder views you may have created to represent inter-view spaces or encapsulation in your user interface.

These cannot be added in Storyboard / IB, but can be used in code in much the same way as a standard `UIView`.

Here's a simple example that adds a "cyan" view and a `UILayoutGuide` to a "container" view, providing 15% of "leading space" to the cyan view:

```
class LayoutGuideExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // create a "container" view
        let cView = UIView()
        cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        view.addSubview(cView)
        
        // constraints for the container view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            cView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            cView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        
        // create a "cyan" view
        let cyanView = UIView()
        cyanView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cyanView.backgroundColor = .cyan

        // add it to the container
        cView.addSubview(cyanView)

        // constrain the cyan view Top / Bottom / Trailing to the container
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cyanView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor),
            cyanView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.bottomAnchor),
            cyanView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // we want the cyan view's leading-edge to be 15% from the
        //  leading-edge of the container
        // but, we can't do that with a leadingAnchor
        //  so, let's add a UILayoutGuide
        
        // create the guide
        let leftGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        
        // add it to the container view
        cView.addLayoutGuide(leftGuide)
        
        // now, we'll constrain the guide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            //  Top / Bottom / Leading to the container
            leftGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor),
            leftGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.bottomAnchor),
            leftGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.leadingAnchor),

            //  Width as 15% of the container Width
            leftGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 15.0 / 100.0),
            
            // and cyan view Leading to the guide's Trailing
            cyanView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftGuide.trailingAnchor),
            
        ])
    }
    
}
```

The result - 15-pts (15%) for a 100-pt "container" view (red outline):

[image]

and, if we change the container width to 200-pts, we get 30-pts (15%) of leading space:

[image]

Comment: May I know what is `ConstraintLayoutGuide`? I could not find much information about it

Comment: @CyberMew - see the **Edit** to my answer.